# Apache CXF non Spring WS-Security with LTPAToken on IBM WAS 8.5

Tags: websphere, ws-security, ltpa

I am trying to implement WS-Security with LTPAToken using CXF without Spring on IBM WAS.

WAS provides a callback handler that does auth and returns the “Run As Subject”. This handler is called com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.auth.callback.LTPATokenCallbackHandler 
OpenCMIS leverages CXF SOAP without Spring Framework. Therefore we need to find out how to configure the WAS call back handler in CXF SOAP implementation for WS Security. The similar configuration is done in xml files when using Spring based implementation, but as OpneCMIS CXF is using non-spring based impl. We need an example of how to do the same in CXF interceptor code.

Comment: Are you using the CXF that is built-in to WAS or packaging your own?  If the latter, what version are you using?

Comment: packaging our own cxf and the version is 3.1.12

Comment: AFAIK if you simply provide the LTPA token in the HTTP request the WebSphere Application Server will create the subject from the LTPA token. If you are having issues getting this going I'd used the trace string specified in this mustgather and open a ticket with IBM.  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21199335

Comment: Ya true, we can provide LTPA token in the HTTP request but that will not be a WS-Security based authentication. IBM WAS has no support for 3rd party(CXF) run time web services and OpenCMIS which leverages CXF non spring no support given to handle WS-Security with LTPA Tokens, OpenCMIS has given support for UsernameToken authentication.

Comment: I have the same problem. The solution I have chosen is to implement with CXF the security based on wsse:BinarySecurityToken and validate the token once obtained against a REST service published in the same Websphere server. With that I get the RunAs in the response of the service or an UNAUTHENTICATED in case the token is not valid.